# Как сделать чтобы при запуске программы на другом компьютере таблица данных в dataGridView не обрезалась?

Tags: c#, winforms

как можно это исправить 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

на одном компьютере нормально запускается на другом вот так вот обрезается один целый столбец и половина другого. код dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill; не помог.

Крайний правый столбец с надписью Итого обрезан наполовину. а столбец который идет после него с надписью Комментарии вообще скрылся.

Comment: якори расставить: для таблички поставить все якори, для панели на которой кнопке - все кроме верхнего

Comment: @dgzargo здравствуйте. а что за якори, не подскажите. где они находятся. в свойствах?